# Symbols, ELF and How To Link in Memory

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, elf

As far as I understand it, the ELF format names all external symbols that are linked by a linker. What I want to do is loading an unlinked ELF and link it in memory and dynamically.

Can someone explain me some necessary details how the linking is down and what changes where in memory?

[update]

To clarify and defend the question from being to broad again here are some more information.

1. I understand jump addresses and can obtain jump addresses from in memory functions using C. So loading a C program I get all those addresses.
2. The parameter passing is known and hard wired there is nothing about it.
3. Within the ASM or C o-file (ELF-Format) I find a symbol table which should be related to the problem but I do not know where in the op codes I have to adapt it and how.

And please do not tell me to read the gnu libc stuff. This is not the problem to face. I neither want to dig into the so format nor do I want to fiddle down their OP code parsing stuff.

So how is the symbol table handled in memory and expressed? It should be a simple answer for someone who knows how it is done.

Comment: Can't you look at the source code of, say, `ld.so`?

Comment: Your question is too broad for Stackoverflow. Please read the ELF manual and ld.so source code. And then come back to ask if you have more specific questions.,

Answer (score 1):

ELF is divided into sections onto disk, but segments in memory.

Basically the loading process means doing the section to segments mapping, and then process fixups.  (including global tables like GOT)

By symbol loading is a different way of loading. It probably does the first process, and then searches for symbol in special tables.

Anyway the best free resource to get a quick insight is to read the "Linkers and Loaders" free ebook book by J. Irvine.

Comment: That is great.. now I have to read a book.... . Honestly, many thanks for the link I will sink my teeth in (while taking a hot bath! :-)).

Comment: The idea is basically to know whats going on. I will have a complex Java loading process where I will for instance provide all stdlib methods by loading a library and asking for specific points using the Unsafe mechanism. So I think the book will bring me all the answers.